# Coverting Circular structure to JSON in Moongoose and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to build a query builder in mongodb with Node.Js as my back-end. So my server side code is like:

```
exports.runPostQuery = function(req, res) {

  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body.q));
  var collection = mongoose.connection.collection(req.body.collection);
  collection.find(JSON.stringify(req.body.q), function(err, docs) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json(docs);
  });
};
```

here req.body.colletion is the collection name and req.body.q consist the query condition . for simplicity I just pass an empty json object in it.
And its throwing me an error as :

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/prateek/webapps/ecommerce-toolbox/node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:228:19)
```

I sear for this error and found that this is the case when we have circular json object like :

```
var a ={};
a.b = a
```

But this is not the case with my JSON . can anyone please explain me the detail about the reason for this error and how to solve this .

Comment: Please show how you pass the empty json object

Comment: I would print out req.body.q and make sure its '{}' as you would expect and then print JSON.stringify(req.body.q) to make sure that works before anything else.